# Unittesting python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I have some function with api

```
def is_car_exist(make, model):
    
    
    url = f'https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/GetModelsForMake/\
    {make.capitalize()}?format=json'
    data = requests.get(url).json()['Results']
    return any(model.capitalize() == car['Model_Name'] for car in data)
```

I have some integration tests:

```
class TestCar(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_is_car_exist(self):
        self.assertTrue(car.is_car_exist('honda', 'civic'))
        self.assertFalse(car.is_car_exist('Mars', 'merana'))
```

Please could you show how Unittest will look like relatively mine function .

Comment: you can look at pytest - https://realpython.com/pytest-python-testing/

Comment: This looks okay. What exactly do you need ?

Comment: how to test requests inside the function ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Use `unittest.mock` module. More details can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

import car


class TestCar(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("requests.get")
    def test_is_car_exist(self, requests_get):
        requests_get.return_value.json.return_value = {"Results": [{"Model_Name": "Civic"}]}

        self.assertTrue(car.is_car_exist('honda', 'civic'))
        self.assertFalse(car.is_car_exist('Mars', 'merana'))
```

## Explanation

`patch` replaces a real object or function with a mock one. It requires a positional argument `target` to be filled. This target needs to be importable by using `path.to.module` notation like normal import.

One way of using it is by using it as a decorator. When using as a decorator, you need to add a parameter to a decorated function. In this case, it is `requests_get`.

`.return_value` is used for function call and what you want it to return.

`requests_get.return_value.json.return_value` means that you want the return value of `requests.get` to be an object which has a method called `json` that returns `{"Results": [{"Model_Name": "Civic"}]}`